# UI freezes while adding many views programmatically

Tags: android

I have views with hundreds layouts (Linears with TextViews), basically it's like list with data.

My presenter after querying the database (sqlbrite, rxjava, its asynchronous) calling method on view which simply create linear with textviews and adds it to some other Linear (its parent for every added view)

With 100+ rows of data on my older phone there is a freeze. How can I reduce it? I can't add views on other thread than UI of course.

Comment: Why don't you use a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.html)?

Comment: @Kunu i will try recycler view. will post results, thank you for advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First thing you need to use a recycler view for list of views. and ofcoarse you can use 100 different types of views with `ViewTypes` of recycler view
2. Second if you insist not to use recycler view then you may better use [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) for adding views at least. Because in some methods of [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) you can access the UI thread and can add elements.
3. Third possibility is with event bus. you will add a method to the fragment/activity and register it with event bus. make it run in background from the tag(java tags). and call it from background thread for adding items(views)

Hope some of it solve your problem :) if not get back to me with more explanation of the question.

P.S [`EventBus`](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is a library work almost the same as `BroadcastReceivers` but it has more features and its more efficient as well.

Comment: i will try recycler view. will post results, thank you for advices

Comment: honestly i didint expected that, but it work a lot better. thank you again